# Template is missing with JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I want to skip JBuilder for certain controllers and just use the as_json defined on the model.  I find I often want to code the JSON uniformly there on the model, but in some cases I need Jbuilder.

Model

```
  def as_json(options={})
    super(only: :uuid)
  end
```

Controller

```
  render json: {success: @model}
```

I continue to get an error exclaiming template is missing.

EDIT:  This is my entire render action right now, this is using devise.

```
  def device_session
    if signed_in?
      render json: {user: current_user}
    else
      render json: {fail: 'Could not authenticate device'}
    end
  end
```

Comment: have you tried `render json: {success: @model} and return`? -- I think that will prevent the default template rendering.

Comment: I have tried that. No luck. Still getting template missing.

Comment: I've tried also adding template: false, template: nil, layout: false, layout: nil, and any logical way to skip JBuilder for this action and nothing seems to work

Comment: According to the rails guide "The rule is that if you do not explicitly render something at the end of a controller action, Rails will automatically look for the action_name.html.erb template in the controller's view path and render it."  So the question might be ... in your code (displayed above) is that `render` in a controller action?  If so, is it the last action?  [See here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)

Comment: Aha -- I think the issue is that you have to override the default Devise controller actions.  Search for "completely override" here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Actually, you were right on, my path through wasn't handling all cases.  I noticed the offending action wasn't this at all. Corrected my issue and it is resolved. I do call return, so let me see if that is the answer. Edit: There is no right answer to this question, as and return is not required, overriding devie isn't required. It works as is if all paths lead to a render.  (Please write that up as an answer @TomHarrisonJr)

Comment: Haha, I guess I am not sure what the answer is, only what it's not :-).  You can answer your own question, and I have no doubt that others will find it useful!  Cheers!